# Can I use Maven to insert BootStrap and JQuery into a Java web application?

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-3

I am pretty new in **Maven** and I am following this tutorial to add the **Twitter BootStrap** CSS framework to a Java web application based on Spring:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

So from what I know it is downloading 2 dependency that are putted into my project. The first one seems related to **BootStrap** and the second one to **JQuery**.

And here my first doubt: in the past I always used Maven (I am not so into it) only to download Java dependencies (jar files containing Java classes). What it means the previous code snippet? That can I use Maven also to download and insert other stuff (as BootStrap and JQuery)?

What exaclty means the:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

into the **bootstrap** artifact definition?

Tnx

Comment: So, you aren't aware of http://webjars.org ..?

Comment: bootstrap 3.2.0 has transitive dependency on jQuery 1.11.1. So if you want to use newer version of jQuery you need to exclude lower version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [webjars documentation](http://www.webjars.org/documentation) says:

> Using a WebJar requires:
>
> 1. The WebJar needs to be a dependency of your application
> 2. The WebJar needs to be in your application's running CLASSPATH
> 3. Your container, web framework, or application needs to serve static assets from Jar files

So basically you are loading a Java .jar file that contains resources. How exactly you load those resources and insert them in your web application is up to you. The documentation contains examples how to load webjars with various web frameworks, including Spring.

---

`<exclusions>` are used to exclude transitive dependencies from your project in maven. Bootstrap requires jquery, so if you add the bootstrap dependency, it will also load jquery by default. If you don't want the jquery jar (for example if you are already loading it by other means) then you should exclude it. I think the intention in the code example was to change the jquery version. There is no need to use exclusion though because the jquery dependency is explicitly defined anyway and will override the jquery version the defined by bootstrap .